# django, unable to create new model, throw DatabaseError 1050, "Table 'XXX' already exists"

Tags: mysql, django, database-migration

I am under production environment so the
`python3 manage.py migrate APP -fake` does not work for me. My company has dev, qa, pre,pre2 and prd environment. I simply added a new model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    column1 = models.ForeignKey(SomeAPP)
    column2 = models.ForeignKey(SomeApp2)
    column3 = CharField(max_length=50)
```

It works fine under all other environments except prd. I tried to delete the table in MySQL and re-build, failed. I did search django_mirgrations table and did not find any record related my brand new app. What are the possible reasons caused this and how can I fix it?  django 1.11.4 and mysql 5.7.

And, I tried to delete the latest migration files under prd environment, successfully built (but when I fetch mysql, the table comes). However, when I tried to alter column, the migration file under other environments is 
`migrations.AlterField` yet in prd migration file it is `migrations.CreateModel`(since I manually ran a DROP TABLE XXX?)

Comment: How did it fail when you tried to delete the table? The actual issue is that it sounds like somehow you have inconsistent migrations between the code as deployed in other stages vs prod. They really ought to be exactly the same.

Comment: I managed to delete that table, yet failed to rebuild. Given 'table existing error'